# OpenCV Assertion Failed CV_IS_MASK_ARR(mask)

Tags: ios, image-processing, opencv, morphing

I'm working with some general OpenCV functions in a sample iOS project, and getting the following error when `cvFindFundamentalMAT` function is called:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (CV_IS_MASK_ARR(mask) && CV_IS_MAT_CONT(mask->type) 
&& (mask->rows == 1 || mask->cols == 1) && mask->rows*mask->cols == count) in 
cvFindFundamentalMat
```

The error seems to be occurring at this function:

```
int calcFundamental(){

if(allPoints.size() != points_count) return -1;

// preparo la matrice delle corrispodenze

points1 = cvCreateMat(2,allPoints.size()/2,CV_32F);
points2 = cvCreateMat(2,allPoints.size()/2,CV_32F);
int count = std::max(points1->cols,points1->rows);
CvMat* status = cvCreateMat(1,count,CV_32F);
std::cout << "status->rows: " << status->rows <<"status->cols: " << status->cols << "count: "<< count << std::endl;
for(int j = 0; j < allPoints.size(); j++){

    if(j%2==0){
        std::cout << allPoints.at(j).x << ' ' << allPoints.at(j).y << std::endl;
        cvSetReal2D(points1,0,j-(int)round(j/2),allPoints.at(j).x);
        cvSetReal2D(points1,1,j-(int)round(j/2),allPoints.at(j).y);
    }else{
        std::cout << allPoints.at(j).x << ' ' << allPoints.at(j).y << std::endl;
        cvSetReal2D(points2,0,j-(int)round(j/2)-1,allPoints.at(j).x);
        cvSetReal2D(points2,1,j-(int)round(j/2)-1,allPoints.at(j).y);
    }
}

fundMat = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32F);
int num = 0;
num = cvFindFundamentalMat(points1,points2,fundMat,CV_FM_8POINT,1.0,0.9999,status);

return num;
```

}

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the type of Mat you are using?

Comment: I am calculating the 8 points in "ViewController.m" class in method "detectFaces".
Then in the "Utility.mm" class, I am initializing the "allPoints" vector in the method "callMainFunctionWithImage".
These points are then used further for creating the fundamentalMat where the crash is occuring.

Answer (score 2):

change `CvMat* status = cvCreateMat(1,count,CV_32F);` to `CvMat* status = cvCreateMat(1,count,CV_8UC1);`

Comment: The debug area now says warping done, but still getting a crash -warping 
done 
SampleOpenCVCodeDemo(7944,0xac5212c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7c75804: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
runs

Comment: Thank you, after resolving the checksum error the crash seems to be fixed.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply on time. If my answer helped you in any way please make me happy by accepting it :)